# preg_match and (non-English) Latin characters?

Tags: php, character-encoding, preg-match, expression

I have a XHTML form where I ask people to enter their full name. I then match that with `preg_match()` using this pattern: `/^[\p{L}\s]+$/`

On my local server running PHP 5.2.13 (PCRE 7.9 2009-04-11) this works fine.
On the webhost running PHP 5.2.10 (PCRE 7.3 2007-08-28) it doesn't match when the entered string contains the Danish Latin character ø ( http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=%F8&mode=char ).

Is this a bug? Is there a work around?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you using the `/u` modifier? Otherwise, UTF-8 has been supported since before PHP 4.3. The PCRE changelog indicates multiple bugs in the 7.x series however.

Comment: Can you check the output of [`preg_last_error`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-last-error.php)?

Comment: @mario No, I don't. I'm not shure how I would use that? If I just add the u-modifier, the pattern doesn't even match on my local server.

Comment: @charles it just gives me 0. Any clues?

Comment: @Jonas, I was hoping that it would be non-zero, as that was my only idea.

Comment: Any ideas for a workaround? Maybe temporarily removing that character from the string, while validating it? I've tried using both str_replace, preg_replace and more - I'm not quite getting it with this text encoding thing.. have no idea what's happening.

Comment: @Jonas, What are the actual goals of the name filter?  Perhaps there might be another way to reach that goal without this specific regex.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, the problem is as presumed. You are not using the `/u` modifier. This means that PCRE will not look for UTF-8 characters.

In any case, this is how it should be done:

```
var_dump(preg_match('/^[\p{L}\s]+$/u', "ø"));
```

And works on all my versions. There might be a bug in others, but that's not likely here.

Your problem is that this also works:

```
var_dump(preg_match('/^[\p{L}\s]+$/', utf8_decode("ø")));
```

Notice that this uses ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8, and leaves out the `/u` modifier. The result is `int(1)`. Obviously PCRE interprets the Latin-1 `ø` as matching `\p{L}` when in non-`/u`nicode mode. (Most of the single-byte \xA0-\xFF are letter symbols in Latin-1, and the 8-bit code point as the same as in Unicode, so that's actually ok.)

Conclusion: Your input is actually ISO-8859-1. That's why it accidentally worked for you without the `/u`. Change that, and be eaxact with input charsets.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, mario! I'm definitely learning something here - first and foremost that I've been too inconsistent with charsets.

Comment: You certainly didn't pick the simplest of topics with that! :} Charsets are always confusion. PS: Gimme an upvote or checkmark if it also helped with your actual task.

Comment: Sorry - I accidentially hit [enter] in the middle of writing this comment:
The u-modifier doesn't work. The utf8_encode()-trick (not _decode) works on my webhost, but not locally.
I really want to get to the bottom of this, so I hope you can clear something up for me: my MySQL tables all have collation latin1_danish_ci, but my PHP scripts is encoded using UTF8, except one danish language-file encoded using ISO Latin 1.
Where do I need to clean things up? Thank you!

Comment: Hmmm, if the /u-modifer doesn't work, then your PCRE setup might really be outdated (some PHP versions were compiled without Unicode until PHP 4.3). -- If you cannot use /unicode in preg_match, then I would have said it's probably best to use Latin-1 everywhere. Your DB is already. Then I guess you would preferrably `recode` all scripts into ISO-8859-1. At the very least you should be able to use utf8_decode on raw strings like in my example.

Comment: You could maybe test `[\\xC0-\\xFF]` instead of `[\p{L}]`. That covers the letters in Latin-1 (only two exceptions). And might be more reliable across PCRE versions.