# preg_match returns different symbols than input string

Tags: php, encoding, character, preg-match, non-latin

[**Resolved**] Adding the modifier `/u` to the regular expression fixes this issue if anyone is struggling with this. Credit to M.I. in the comments :)

Consider the following code:

```
var_dump('Trimiteţi');
preg_match('/^([\p{L}]+)/', 'Trimiteţi', $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

I am using it to filter a word that might have non-latin characters using `\p{L}`, also notice that I don't use the end string `$` regular expression symbol in the `preg_match`

Now to the problem, when executing the code locally I receive this output:

```
string 'TrimiteÅ£i' (length=10)
Array ( [0] => TrimiteÅ [1] => TrimiteÅ )
```

I tried executing the code in the [PHP sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3c127fa4355ed3bdc5324e62a4135f76030aef3e), and it outputs something similar:

```
string(10) "Trimiteţi"
Array
(
    [0] => Trimite�
    [1] => Trimite�
)
```

Notice that at least this time it didn't ruin the original `var_dump` word.

What is going on? Why using preg_match changes the word? Worst part about this is, if I add `$` to the end of the regular expression, it will **NOT MATCH**, since I suppose those transformed symbols could not be interpreted as a string end or something. Please, help me

Edit: the file encoding that I'm running is set to "text/x-php; charset=utf-8"
Edit2: Additionally, I used [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/), and when using REGULAR EXPRESSION "^[\p{L}]+$" and word "Trimiteţi" it seems to match. You can even switch the REGULAR EXPRESSION TO "^([\p{L}]+)$", adding the capturing group, and the site outputs:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-9]   `Trimiteţi`
```

Comment: interesting it should work, maybe the encoding when displaying in your console is the problem. try saving it to a file and open with a text editor.

Comment: preg_mach is a little different from simple regex pattern, test your patterns here https://www.functions-online.com/preg_match.html

Comment: @M.I. Thank you for your response. I'm looking at it through the browser, but console output behaves the same.  Saving $matches to a file didn't help too, it outputs the same, changed letters. The site you provided behaves exactly like my local copy, no matches when using $, and changed text when using without

Comment: Found an answer to your problem here on SO. Try this `preg_match('/^([\p{L}]+)/u', 'Trimiteţi', $matches);`

Comment: Here you find more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424494/preg-match-and-non-english-latin-characters

Comment: Yes, the `/u` modifier helped, thank you so very much. Make it as an answer so I can mark is as correct

Comment: was already answered, give a plus to the poster :)