# Php preg_match not working with óá

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

Hey my routing script isnt working with special chars and i dont have any idea anymore why or how to fix it.

My Url: `/test/x/hállò/123`
My Router added URL: /test/:varx/:variableZ/123

```
$route['url'] ="/test/x/:name/123";
$reqMet = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$route['method'] = "GET";
$reqUrl = "/test/x/hállò/123";
$matches = Array();

$pattern = "@^" . preg_replace('/\\\:[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+/', '([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)', preg_quote($route['url'])) . "$@D";

if($reqMet == $route['method'] && preg_match($pattern, $reqUrl, $matches)) {
  echo "THIS SHOULD BE THE OUTPUT";
}
```

So its not working with words like lòl or Háy but i get back the correct Url but with things like article/test/123 all is perfect.

Hope someone have a fix for me. 
Thanks

## EDIT

So this is working

```
$router->addRoute('GET','/test/x/hállò/123','home/main',false);
```

URL >> [http://localhost/test/x/hállò/123](http://localhost/test/x/h%C3%A1ll%C3%B2/123)

BUT this not

```
$router->addRoute('GET','/test/x/:name/123','home/main',false`);
```

URL >> [http://localhost/test/x/hállò/123](http://localhost/test/x/h%C3%A1ll%C3%B2/123)

:name is for variables which are replaceable like Article id oder whatever.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I preg\_replace special character like 'Prêt-à-porter'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050723/how-can-i-preg-replace-special-character-like-pr%c3%aat-%c3%a0-porter) and also [preg_match and (non-English) Latin characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424494/preg-match-and-non-english-latin-characters)

Comment: @chris85 yes but you should get :S i want to get it

Comment: @C0dekid nah its not solving my problem

Comment: `Nope.. not working` means the pattern matched, what is expected here? Simplified reproducible version of your code. https://3v4l.org/8Jccp You regexs also could just be `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+` the underscore isn't special and the hyphen just needs to be last or first.

Comment: In PHP preg_ functions, you need to use `/u` modifier if you want to deal with Unicode chars. Also, are you sure `$reqMet == $route['method']`? If you remove this condition, you get the "THIS IS THE OUTPUT" - [**see this demo**](https://ideone.com/nGatS0).

Comment: You seem to forget to tag the question appropriately. If it is zend-framework, add it.

Comment: @Juan Your question and code need to demonstrate the exact issue. Are you using `preg_` functions?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It isnt :D its my own

Comment: @chris85 the code is all i use in this script theres notihinge much more before it

Comment: Cool, then what pattern is the `:name` translated into?

Comment: This is what it is when its patternd   /test/x/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)

Comment: so this ([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+) should be replace the :name with hálló but it doesnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it seems you may need to include several other accented and/or non-English letters, I will only include the letters you mentioned.

An alternative and super-lenient pattern (perhaps not secure enough) would be `\\\:[^\/]+`

Code:

```
$route['url'] ="/test/x/:name/123";
$reqUrl = "/test/x/hállò/123";

echo "Input:\n";
var_export(preg_quote($route['url']));

$pattern="@^".preg_replace('/\\\:[a-zA-Z0-9áò_-]+/','([a-zA-Z0-9áò_-]+)',preg_quote($route['url']))."$@D";
//                                         ^^ new letters here: ^^

if(preg_match($pattern, $reqUrl, $matches)) {
    echo "\n\nOutput\n";
    var_export($matches);
}else{
    echo "\n\nNo Match";
}
```

Displays:

```
Input:
'/test/x/\\:name/123'

Output
array (
  0 => '/test/x/hállò/123',
  1 => 'hállò',
)
```

Comment: i saw it today :) i will test it out but it seems like to be a stable good answer and solve for it.

Comment: your the mvp dude :D!